# Array Can't Get Vars PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is probably very simple but for some reason i cant get my code to echo the variable. Sorry Im new to php.

```
$file ="https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/los/view/All_Borrowers? 
authtoken=xxx&raw=true";
$bors = file_get_contents($file);
$array = json_decode($bors);
$vars = get_object_vars($array);
```

Returns

```
 Array
(
[Borrowers] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Full_Name] => Steve Smith
                [Email] => fsgfsz@gmail.com
                [Address] => Granby Ct., Aurora, CO, 80012
                [Position] => Borrower
                [ID] => 1159827000004784102
                [Mobile] => +13035550050
                [Application] => Application 1 - 1159827000004784096
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Full_Name] => Stacy H Sanchez
                [Email] => dfd@gmail.com
                [Address] => Granby, 80012
                [Position] => Co-Borrower
                [ID] => 1159827000004784108
                [Mobile] => +13035550957
                [Application] => Application 1 - 1159827000004784096
            )

    )

)
```

Im using:

```
   echo $vars["Borrowers"][0]["Full_Name"];
```

but its throwing an error. Not sure where im going wrong.

Comment: *"but its throwing an error."* - Being what exactly?

Comment: http error 500 / page wont even load. When i remove the echo, it loads fine.

Comment: `Array => Array => Object` not `Array => Array => Array`.

Comment: Check your logs, and/or enable error reporting. That should shed some light.

Comment: @Script47 how do i get it in the format of array -> array -> array?

Comment: [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'s second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Full_name is an object property, not array index

```
echo $vars["Borrowers"][0]->Full_Name;
```